# Convert nested JSON to nested HashMap

Tags: java, json

How can we convert the nested json to nested hashmap without creating the pojo classes.

```
{
  "IdeskFields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "CLIENT_TAX_TYPE_ID",
      "values": [
        {
          "key": "dataType",
          "value": "Integer"
        },
        {
          "key": "CLIENT_TAX_TYPE_VAT",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "key": "CLIENT_TAX_TYPE_GST",
          "value": "8"
        },
        {
          "key": "CLIENT_TAX_TYPE_Tax",
          "value": "9"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Need to be converted to Map<String, Map<String, String>> map

Comment: You cannot directly convert the json string to `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`. If you observe, the root element is of type `List`. Then this list has specific object. This object internally has values of type `Map`. The the most apt solution would be to convert the json to `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ObjectMapper` from `jackson`.

```
Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

A map will be an instance of

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the `Gson` library then you can do something like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Map map = gson.fromJson(str, Map.class);
```

But that would leave to the library to determine the type of values.

Therefore better way to use `Gson#fromJson(String, Type)` something like below:

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>>() {}.getType();

Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> map = gson.fromJson(str, mapType);
```

**I use Object as inner map value type because your values are different i.e string and list of another map.**